# Passing arguments in jQuery post to a method in controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

In ASP.NET MVC I was using this script to call a method in controller:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getBookedByUser", "Home")',
    data: "2",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#someElement').html(data); // add the returned html to the DOM

        console.log(data);
    },
});
</script>
```

and this is the method I call:

```
public async Task getBookedByUser(string id)
{
     BenchesService benchService = new BenchesService();
     List<Bench> obj = await benchService.getLastBenchByUser(id);

     userBench = obj.ElementAt(0);
}
```

My problem is that `id` in my controller method is `null`. It doesn't assume the value "2" as I intend.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  You need to setup the JSON to include your `id` property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getBookedByUser", "Home")',
    data: { id: '2' },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#someElement').html(data); // add the returned html to the DOM

        console.log(data);
    },
 });
```